# Why is my Verilog code for Mealy-type sequential circuit not working?

Tags: verilog, sequential-logic

I am supposed to write code for a circuit which outputs (z) 1 whenever the 2-bit input (x) is either 00 or 11 for two consecutive clock cycles. I feel like I'm close, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Help! It's 1 module and 1 test bench. I also attached the waveform and state diagrams. For some reason the output (shown in red) is 1 whenever the input is 00 or 11 (shown in yellow), regardless of the previous state.
[image][image]

```
module EqulNchecker
(
output reg z_out,
input [1:0] x_in, 
input clock, reset
);
reg [1:0] state, next_state;
parameter S0 = 2'b01 && 2'b10, S1 = 2'b00, S2 = 2'b11;
always @ (posedge clock, negedge reset)
begin
    if (reset == 0) state = S0;
    else state = next_state;
end


always @ (state, x_in)
begin
        if(x_in == 2'b11) next_state = S2;
        else if(x_in == 2'b00) next_state = S1;
        else next_state = S0;
end    
    
always @ (state, x_in)
begin
    case (state)
        S0: z_out = 0;
        S1: if(x_in == 2'b00) z_out <= 1; else  z_out <= 0; 
        S2: if(x_in == 2'b11) z_out <= 1; else  z_out <= 0;
    endcase
end
endmodule




module test_EqualNchecker();
wire z_out_test;
reg [1:0] x_in_test;
reg clock_test, reset_test;

EqulNchecker M0(z_out_test, x_in_test, clock_test, reset_test);
initial #260 $finish ;
initial begin clock_test = 0;
    forever #10 clock_test = ~clock_test;
end

initial fork
    reset_test = 0;
    #10 reset_test = 1;
    #20 reset_test = 0;
    #30 reset_test = 1;
    
    x_in_test = 2'b00;
    #40 x_in_test = 2'b10;
    #60 x_in_test = 2'b11;
    #80 x_in_test = 2'b00;
    #100 x_in_test = 2'b11;
    #120 x_in_test = 2'b11;
    #140 x_in_test = 2'b10;
    #160 x_in_test = 2'b11;
    #180 x_in_test = 2'b00;
    #200 x_in_test = 2'b00;
    #220 x_in_test = 2'b10;
join    
endmodule
```

Comment: Explain "not working" with simulation waveforms.

Comment: If you have the code and the testbench then you should simulate your design. Observe internal signals and state variables. Presumably you have a state diagram so you know the meaning of S0, S1, etc. You are really in a much better position to find the mistake than any of us.

Comment: This looks suspicious: `S0 = 2'b01 && 2'b10`

Comment: I have added the waveform and state diagram, as well as a better description of my issue.

Comment: @toolic: Surprisingly, that assignment actually works in this design! Perhaps not quite as intended...

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that in a Mealy machine, the output(s) need to be registered, too — in addition to the state variable(s), that is.

Also, the assignment `S0 = 2'b01 && 2'b10` works, but not in the way you expected. The `&&` operator is true (one) if both of its operands are true (nonzero). Since both `2'b01` and `2'b10` are nonzero, this assigns 1 to `S0`. Since `S1` is 0 and `S2` is 3, it all works out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. Pretty sure it was an issue with not using blocking statements where I needed them.